# Undefined method error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model where students can enter information about themselves and others can view them. Since there are a lot of profiles, I have added a search section too. If they want only CS majors, they can select from a drop down. I had things like major, college... today I added "level", which is level of education and I get an error (Error shown at the end). I know this is long, but any help would be really really useful. Thanks!

(*Userinfo is the student model*)

My controller looks like this:

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :log_impression]

    def index
        @userinfors = Userinfo.search(params[:search])
        @search = Search.new
        @college = Userinfo.uniq.pluck(:college)
        @major = Userinfo.uniq.pluck(:major)
        @level = Userinfo.uniq.pluck(:level)
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = current_user.build_userinfo
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = current_user.build_userinfo(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @userinformation.update(userinfo_params)
            redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @userinformation.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major, :token, :skills, :level)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

My information fill out form (*please note how the way of input is different in major and level of edu, maybe thats the problem?*):

```
<%= simple_form_for @userinformation, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: true, label: 'Full name' %>
  <%= f.input :college, required: true, label: 'Name of college' %>
  <%= f.input :gpa, required: true, label: 'Enter GPA' %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, label: 'Enter email address' %>
  <%= f.input :major, required: true, label: 'Major' %>
  <%= f.input :level, collection: ["College undergrad", "College grad"], required: true, label: 'Level of education' %>
  <%= f.input :skills, required: true, label: 'Skills' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Create account' %>
<% end %>
```

Search controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @search = Search.new
        @college = Userinfo.uniq.pluck(:college)
        @major = Userinfo.uniq.pluck(:major)
        @level = Userinfo.uniq.pluck(:level)
    end

    def create
        @search = Search.create(search_params)
        redirect_to @search
    end

    def show
        @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
        def search_params
            params.require(:search).permit(:keyword, :college, :min_gpa, :major, :token, :level )
        end
end
```

Search model:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

    def search_userinfos

        userinfos = Userinfo.all

        userinfos = userinfos.where(["name LIKE ?","%#{keyword}%"]) if keyword.present?
        userinfos = userinfos.where(["college LIKE ?", college]) if college.present?
        userinfos = userinfos.where(["cast(gpa as numeric) >= ?", min_gpa]) if min_gpa.present?
        userinfos = userinfos.where(["major LIKE ?", major]) if major.present?
        userinfos = userinfos.where(["level LIKE ?", level]) if level.present?
        userinfos = userinfos.order("gpa")

        return userinfos
    end

end
```

This is where the search section is displayed (index view):

```
<%= simple_form_for @search do |s| %>
    <%= s.input :keyword, label: 'Name' %>  
    <label>College</label>
    <%= s.select :college, options_for_select(@college), :include_blank => true %>
    <%= s.input :min_gpa, label: "Minimum GPA" %>
    <label>Major</label>
    <%= s.select :major, options_for_select(@major), :include_blank => true %>
    <label>Job type</label>
    <%= s.select :level, options_for_select(@level), :include_blank => true  %>
    <%= s.button :submit, "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

The error I get when I try to visit the index view:

```
NoMethodError in Userinfos#index
Showing app-path/index.html.erb where line #25 raised:

undefined method `level' for #<Search:0x000000139d6c38>
```

Line 25 is:

```
<%= s.select :level, options_for_select(@level), :include_blank => true  %>
```

Everything works if I remove that line. When I show the education level in the user profile page, it works perfectly.

Schema for searches:

```
  create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "keyword"
    t.string   "college"
    t.decimal  "min_gpa"
    t.string   "major"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Could you put the schema for the `Search` model?

Comment: @Jeremie done. I think I see the problem. I have to do "rails g migration add_level_to_searches level:string". right?

Comment: Yes, you don't have still the level attribute in your model, create the migration and then run `rails db:migrate`.

Comment: Thanks guys, please write it as an answer if any one of you needs the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented, you do not have a `level` attribute in your `Search` model.

```
rails g migration add_level_to_searches level:string
```

And of course

```
rails db:migrate
```

Happy to help!